# Mongoose populate depending on conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

My service uses MongoDB and Mongoose. I have two DBs: Users and Posts. In Posts schema I have parameters:

- **"author"**, that contains userId from Users DB
- **"anonymous"**, a boolean-parameter that shows if the post is anonymous or not.

I can't solve the problem: when I request data from Posts DB I want to populate author in the **"author"** parameter only for non-anonymous posts, for anonymous ones I'd like to return **null** or not to return this parameter at all.

I've tried to use "match", but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Code example:

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    author: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    anonymous: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

For population I use pre:

```
postSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'author',
    select: '_id login',
  });
  next();
});
```